# haskell mod plugin for emacs - REPL not work

Tags: haskell, emacs, interactive, read-eval-print-loop

I have installed emacs and haskell-mod, I load the file into emacs star the repL with c-c c-l, appear the prompter(that with lambda), but when I type for example 1+2 and hit Enter nothing is happen. Should I use other key or why it didn't work ?
Thanks,
Sorin

Answer (score 1):

Emacs' shell buffer doesn't get along too well with the Unicode (lambda) prompt. You can manually set the prompt with `:set prompt "ghci> "`.

To automatically run the set prompt command when the shell starts up, edit your [.ghci file](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html) to include the above set command.